# How can I copy websites from one windows server to another and retain/recreate machine specific accounts?

Tags: windows, permissions, web-server

I need to move a lot of websites. I researched and learned how to use robocopy to mirror copy the content along with the ACLs. That works fine for the domain accounts. The problem is that there are also machine accounts referenced in the ACLs, and they are all over the place. Is there a way to re-create those on the the fly using the existing ones? For example, to replace server1\IIS_IUSRS with server2\IIS_IUSRS?

Comment: What version OS/IIS? They made those ACLs well known SIDs quite a while back. http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use icacls after (robo)copying your data:

```
icacls dir /remove:g user /t /c
icacls dir /grant user:permission /t /c
```

you can get the permissions using icals /dir. The /t switch means "t"raverse subfolders and /c is "c"ontinue on errors (but show them). If you don't care about errors use /q for quiet.

You can find the documentation on icals here: http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html